# If case within string in JavaScript with variable either inside quotation marks or NULL?

Tags: javascript, sql

This question is difficult to title but easy to show. I would like to add multiple sets of values to an SQL insert such as

```
var sqlInsertString = `INSERT INTO events (url) VALUES`
var sqlInsertValuesString = `(`('${event.url ? event.url : null}'), null, 1, 2, 3)`

pg_client.query(sqlInsertString + sqlInsertValuesString)
```

this happens in a loop and thus the separation of insert string and values string. Now, what I want to happen is that if event.url contains a url it should insert the url as `'https://www.example.com'` (with quotation marks) but if event.url is empty, it should insert null.

My code above will insert 'null' (with quotation marks) instead of an actual null in the database. Removing the quotation marks will cause errors because of the ':' in the url.

How do I, in `sqlInsertValuesString` either provide a valid url string OR a 'real' `null` (without quotation marks) with this method?

Comment: Don't concatenate for database queries - that's opening you up to SQL injection. Use parameterized queries instead

Comment: This function would not be open for injection but it is a good point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one reason to use parametrised queries, not just preventing injection attacks. They make it as simple as

```
pg_client.query(
  "INSERT INTO events (url, nothing, one, two, three) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)",
  [event.url || null, null, 1, 2, 3]
)
.then(res => ...)
.catch(err => ...)
```

No quoting necessary, the driver handles all the mechanics behind the scenes.

So even if you are not making your program safer, it is still good to use parametrised queries at least for legibility, and also for practice: if you get into a habit of using parametrised queries *always*, you will not need to think whether an injection is possible, and you will never make a mistake of misjudging it and leaving a security hole in your program.

Comment: Yes! This was the best solution and what I was looking to do in the first place but could never really figure out how to solve it. Most elegant and best solution overall. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you particularly want to use the backticks, you can do this

```js
var event = {};
event.url = 'http://someurl.com';
var sqlInsertString = "INSERT INTO events (url, a, b, c, d) VALUES ";
var sqlInsertValuesString = "('" + (event.url ? event.url + "'" : null) + ", null, 1, 2, 3)";

console.log(sqlInsertString + sqlInsertValuesString);

var event = {};
var sqlInsertString = "INSERT INTO events (url, a, b, c, d) VALUES ";
var sqlInsertValuesString = "(" + (event.url ? "'" + event.url + "'" : null) + ", null, 1, 2, 3)";

console.log(sqlInsertString + sqlInsertValuesString);
```

Comment: But as noted in the comments, best to avoid passing parameters through concatenation

Answer (score 1):

It probably makes sense to split the assignment for clarity:

```
let eventUrl = event.url ?? null;
const sqlInsertString = `INSERT INTO events (url) VALUES (${eventUrl}, null, 1, 2, 3)`
```

I have used the [coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) operator for the `eventUrl`

Comment: That is a very elegant solution, it still doesn't address the real issue with the quotations marks needed for event.url but it may be very useful for other parts of my code!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
`(${event.url ? `'${event.url}'` : `null`})`
```

So there are only single quotes around the url if it exists, and not for nulls.

Comment: Thanks. I realized I didn't write my code exactly as I am using it, so I edited the code in my question. When I run this I get: "`(${event.url ? `'${event.url}'` : `null`})`,                ^SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list". I assume this has to do with that I, in fact, have sqlInsertValuesString wrapped in `as well and that the parenthesis is left "in the code" so to say.

Answer (score 0):

If someone finds this through Google I also found that escaping the backtick works as well:

```
${event.url ? (`\'` + event.url + `\'`) : null},
```

but the chosen answer is better.